# How to conditionlly change ownership of a file?

Tags: chown

I was tasked to change the owner of a file called `hello` to `vincent` only if the owner was `guillame`.
I tried to use `chmod vincent:guillame hello` but this is not working. Please, I need help to solve the task.

Comment: You can see the name of the owner of a file with `stat --format="%N" file`. Read `man stat chmod chown`.

Answer (score 2):

`chown` is the command used to change ownership of files, not `chmod`.

```bash
find hello -user guillame -exec chown vincent {} \;
```

This uses `find` with the file `hello` as the "search path".  If the `hello` file's owner is `guillame`, `find` will execute `chown vincent` with the file as its next argument, changing the file's ownership to `vincent`.  If the owner of the file is not `guillame`, nothing will happen.

This command ought to be portable to any Unix system.

Note that this assumes that the current user has privileges that allow changing the file ownership.  You may have to run either `chown` or `find` itself as root using `sudo` or `doas` or whatever other way you usually run a utility with escalated privileges on your system.

Answer (score -1):

For just one file called `hello`:

```bash
/usr/bin/test "$(stat --format="%U" hello)" = "guillame" && sudo chown vincent foo
```

Comment: Note that on Alpine Linux (or any Busybox system), you'd use `stat -c %U filename` (which incidentally also works on system where `--format` is valid); on OpenBSD, FreeBSD, NetBSD, and macOS, it's `stat -f %Su filename`.